# UART communication checksum

Tags: serial-port, uart, crc

I am trying to decode/understand a serial (UART) communication protocol between an air conditioner and wifi module. I have used Docklight to sniff communication, I have some results how to switch on the AC unit and switch off, change modes etc. But I do not understand how to calculate CRC. Here is an example:

```
18/08/2020 17:15:28.292 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 04 4F 39
```

Communication log please see full log below:

```
Mobile APP ON
18/08/2020 17:15:06.001 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:15:06.651 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 18 F3
18/08/2020 17:15:15.917 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:15:16.589 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 18 F3 
18/08/2020 17:15:25.928 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:15:26.605 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 18 F3
POWER ON FROM APP -
18/08/2020 17:15:28.292 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 04 4F 39 
18/08/2020 17:15:28.982 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3D 6A
18/08/2020 17:15:35.928 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:15:36.653 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 8F 7B 
18/08/2020 17:15:45.496 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 42 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 05 83 05
18/08/2020 17:15:46.151 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AA FE
18/08/2020 17:15:46.531 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:15:46.909 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 18 F3 
18/08/2020 17:15:56.029 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:15:56.719 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 18 F3 
18/08/2020 17:16:01.325 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 1E AC B2 00 00 63 00 00 0D 01 01 01 69 03 A8 C0 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3B AA 20
                       - AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:16:06.621 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 18 F3 
18/08/2020 17:17:31.039 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 1E AC B2 00 00 64 00 00 0D 01 01 01 69 03 A8 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3C
                       - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:18:02.095 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 00 A9 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C C9 43
18/08/2020 17:18:02.220 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 1E AC B2 00 00 65 00 00 0D 01 01 01 69 03 A8 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3B
                       - AA 1E AC B2 00 00 66 00 00 0D 01 01 01 69 03 A8 C0 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 38
```

(...)

```
Eco on in cool mode -
                                       - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 1A EA 2A
18/08/2020 17:22:05.042 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 10 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 85 35 
18/08/2020 17:22:11.244 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:22:11.925 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 10 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 37 E6 
18/08/2020 17:22:21.325 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:22:21.985 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 10 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 37 E6 
Eco off in cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:22:22.025 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 1B A2 F1
18/08/2020 17:22:22.684 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 77 53 
18/08/2020 17:22:31.234 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:22:31.923 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C C5 68 
18/08/2020 17:22:41.272 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:22:41.901 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C C5 68 
18/08/2020 17:22:51.311 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:22:51.964 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 14 18 
Fan auto cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:22:52.421 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 1C 21 71
18/08/2020 17:22:53.133 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A6 23 
18/08/2020 17:23:01.326 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:23:01.997 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 14 18
18/08/2020 17:23:11.373 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:23:12.108 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 66 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 14 18
Fan high cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:23:15.540 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 50 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 1D 73 34
18/08/2020 17:23:16.272 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 50 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A D5
18/08/2020 17:23:21.383 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:23:22.061 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 50 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C B8 8A
18/08/2020 17:23:30.203 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 1E 89 31
18/08/2020 17:23:30.881 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4B A8 
18/08/2020 17:23:31.278 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:23:31.992 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C F9 5D
18/08/2020 17:23:41.298 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:23:41.972 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C F9 5D
18/08/2020 17:23:42.681 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 50 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 1F CF D6
18/08/2020 17:23:43.373 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 50 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A D5 
Fan mid cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:23:51.277 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 20 28 90
18/08/2020 17:23:51.931 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4B A8 
18/08/2020 17:23:52.059 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:23:52.670 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C F9 5D 
18/08/2020 17:24:01.275 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:24:01.986 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C F9 5D 
18/08/2020 17:24:01.986 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 1E AC B2 00 00 69 00 00 0D 01 01 01 69 03 A8 C0 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 AA 23
                       - AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 21 CB 00
18/08/2020 17:24:09.492 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 66 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 B7
18/08/2020 17:24:11.350 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:24:11.940 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 8B E1
18/08/2020 17:24:13.682 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 22 94 22
18/08/2020 17:24:14.351 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 3C 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 22 D3
```

...

```
Fan low in cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:24:17.570 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 23 77 52
18/08/2020 17:24:18.240 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 39 D0
18/08/2020 17:24:21.317 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C 
18/08/2020 17:24:21.988 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 8B E1 
18/08/2020 17:24:31.399 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:24:32.046 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 49 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 8B E1 
20 st in cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:24:38.338 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 44 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 24 D1 FC
18/08/2020 17:24:39.031 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 44 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4F BF 
18/08/2020 17:24:41.429 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:24:42.098 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 44 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C FD 74 
18/08/2020 17:24:51.308 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:24:51.978 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 44 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C FD 74 
21 st in cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:24:55.134 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 45 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 25 18 B3
18/08/2020 17:24:55.799 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 45 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A5 68
18/08/2020 17:25:01.468 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:25:02.113 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 45 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 17 59 
22 st in cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:25:09.362 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 46 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 26 5A 6F
18/08/2020 17:25:10.035 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 46 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 82 8A 
18/08/2020 17:25:11.392 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:25:12.024 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 46 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C 30 3F 
23 st in cool mode -
18/08/2020 17:25:20.731 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 23 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 40 43 47 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 27 93 34
18/08/2020 17:25:21.405 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 02 C0 01 47 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 A3
18/08/2020 17:25:21.452 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:25:22.119 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 47 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C DA 94 
18/08/2020 17:25:31.572 [Wifi to Ciat] - AA 20 AC 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 81 00 FF 03 FF 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 CD 9C
18/08/2020 17:25:32.247 [CIAT to WIFI] - AA 22 AC 00 00 00 00 00 03 03 C0 01 47 28 7F 7F 00 30 00 00 00 65 5F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 9C DA 94
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you think there is a CRC? _Why_ do you think there is a CRC? I see lots of repetition in the last two bytes, so those are probably not a CRC.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have been looking at last three bytes, which are changing with every sent message from WIFI to AC UNIT(CIAT). Third from the end is increasing by, but the last two seems to be different all the times, can you please tell me where you can sie lots of repetition? Thank you

Comment: Ok, I see now that it is the entire message that is repeating, not just the last two or three bytes.

Comment: It looks like three of your messages are missing the two possible check bytes at the end. They start with `AA 1E AC B2 00 00 64`, `AA 1E AC B2 00 00 65`, and `AA 1E AC B2 00 00 66`.

Comment: Hi Mark, would you be able to explain to me what are the last three bytes if not CRC please. I really struggle to understand it.

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The last two bytes are not a CRC of the message. They do not obey the linearity property of a CRC.